# Apache configuration to accept all data

Tags: apache-2.2, php, logging

I have apache running on port 7979 to talk with a device that sends data to webserver and later will run php scripts to process and send reply xml.

The problem now is that it sends data like

POST HTTP/1.1
Content-Type:text/xml
Content-Length:369
Followed by XML

When apache sees this it gives a 400 error. Since the device cannot be changed is there any way to accept the full data sent from the device and write to some log? Currently apache simply keeps sending 400 errors back. If there was a way to log the entire xml or create some custom handler for 400 error then the xml could be read by a php script.

Looking forward to solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If apache think the request is incorrect, you couldn't use Apache. Maybe check on (x)inetd/nc server with a PHP script launched. Your script will receive all the connection and use it as it want.

Comment: thanks, xinetd with php might work. let me try that thanks. Any pointer on how to get started on centos with xinetd and php? Searching the internets on howto now.

Comment: Look at xinetd : you just need to open a port and when a connection arrive, the PHP software will be launched. I think you should read stdin in PHP to see the datas.

Sorry, I don't have any Howto.

Comment: Here is a test :
In inetd.conf :
88 stream tcp nowait root /home/user/testInet.php

And testInet.php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

 $fp = fopen ("php://stdin", "r");

 $line = fgets ($fp);

 echo "TEST\n";

 exit;
?>

If you connect with telnet localhost 88, send a text (like your client), and you will receive the text "TEST"

Of course, it is just a proof of concept, there is no security

Comment: I managed to get this working did some PHP socket programming without inetd / nc server

Just plain PHP and it works great. Just followed http://www.functionblog.com/?p=67=1